# Using MongoDB To Store Unique Address

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am a n00b working with MongoDB and want to clean up our database of addresses. We have multiple documents that could have the same address in them.  All the addresses have been uniformly formatted where there should be no issues of spelling or abbreviations, but I've been unable to figure out how to insert unique addresses only in the the collection.

```js
db.testing.createIndex( { address: 1 }, { unique: true } );
db.testing.update(
        {address: 
    {
      street: "99 Main Street",
      city: "Boston",
      zip: "66666"
    }}, 
        { upsert: true});

db.testing.update(
        {address: 
    {
      street: "99 Main Street",
      city: "Boston",
      zip: "66666"
    }}, 
        { upsert: true});

db.testing.update(
        {address: 
    {
      street: "199 Main Street",
      city: "Boston",
      zip: "66666"
    }}, 
        { upsert: true});


db.getCollection('testing').find({});
```

The above should output 2 addresses only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error with your update syntax. The syntax for an update, as explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), is the following:

```js
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     "upsert": <boolean>,
     "multi": <boolean>,
     "writeConcern": <document>
   }
);
```

You are missing the `<query>` part, which means your update never matches any existing documents, which means the duplicate addresses are not inserted. If instead you executed `db.testing.insert({ "address": { "street": "99 Main Street", "city": "Boston", "zip": "66666" }});` twice, you would get the following error:

```js
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.testing.$address_1 dup key: { : { street: \"99 Main Street\", city: \"Boston\", zip: \"66666\" } }"
    }
})
```

If you want to insert a new document without raising an error, but checking for duplicates, you can use the following (using `mongo` shell syntax).

```js
> var doc = { "address": { "street": "99 Main Street", "city": "Boston", "zip": "66666" }};
> db.testing.update(doc, { "$set": doc }, { "upsert": true });
```

That will return something like the following if it is a new insert:

```js
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("55418381819bc7aeea60f83a")
})
```

Or the following if the document already exists:

```js
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

What it does is matches a document with the `address` of the document you want to insert. If it exists, it doesn't do anything, otherwise it inserts it.

Comment: How do I get it to insert if it's not there else skip without throwing an error?

Comment: Added that scenario to the answer.